# Table inside scrollable container still causes container width to grow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap grid. I am currently facing a strange issue with displaying tables inside Bootstrap column.

I have a table with some columns, displayed inside a div (table container). The table container has `col-md-9` bootstrap class, so its width is set to 75%. However, at a certain point if the table contains too much content and/or column, it causes the container's width to expand. Here is a standalone example: https://output.jsbin.com/xowihu

Here is a screenshot. Notice the gray box getting pushed outside, causing the layout to look broken:
[image: issue]

And, when I removed some columns from the table, it works and looks as expected:
[image: expected]

The thing that confuses me is that, I have already specified `overflow: scroll` on the table container. Why is content length affecting container width?

**I have tried:**

- Setting `table-layout: fixed` on the table, and `word-wrap: break-word` on the table cells. This works, however the table contents are visually horrible; one word is broken into 3 lines, etc.
- Setting `max-width` on the table container works, but it has to be in `px` unit. This might be last resort (and will be applied via Javascript) since site has various layout widths.

**EDIT** Link to code: https://jsbin.com/xowihu/edit

Comment: using `max-width: x%` not works??

Comment: You **cannot limit a tables width, nor height, with css** as long as you don't change the display property to for example `display: block;` (which has all sorts of unwanted side effects, you really don't want to go there). You need to give the html element that contains the table the `overflow-x: scroll;`.

Comment: @RohitKumar No.. it only works using explicit units (px, em, etc)

Comment: @connexo I have already added `overflow-x: scroll`. In fact, I've tried adding `overflow: auto`, and all variants..

Comment: Adding that to the **table** does **nothing**.

Comment: @connexo I know. I added that to the table's container (a div element).

Comment: If that div has a max-width (unit irrelevant), it has to work.

Comment: @connexo No, it doesn't. Please see the example: https://output.jsbin.com/xowihu

Comment: Please link to your actual ***code***, not just the output.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xowihu/edit

Answer (score 0):

When I put the `<div class="row">`  that was inside the `<table class="table">` outside the table,tr,td it works just fine..

```
<div class="col-md-7 slide-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-2" style="height: 250px; background-color: lightgreen">Some Label</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 scrollable">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem libero sequi tempore necessitatibus tempora, porro, iure, nisi dicta, rerum enim natus facilis voluptatum soluta dolore molestias vero odit eaque veniam.</p>
                    <table class="table" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Hello</td>
                          <td>Lipsumdolor</td>
                          <td>Lipsum Gen</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Hello</td>
                          <td>Lipsumdolor</td>
                          <td>LipsumLipsumLipsumLipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Hello</td>
                          <td>Lipsumdolor</td>
                          <td>Lipsum Gen</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                          <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                          <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                          <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                          <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/120x120"><br>
                <a href="#">Click to enlarge</a>
              </div>
            </div><table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

SO everything that I did was, get the div class="row" that is inside the

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
```

And put it underneath the

```
<div class="col-md-7 slide-content">
```

Comment: What do you mean "When I put the div ROW outside the table,tr,td it works just fine" - where else would you put it??

Comment: In the code that he is using, he has

<div class="col-md-7 slide-content"><table><tr><td><div class="row">

So I changed to

<div class="col-md-7 slide-content"><div class="row">

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva Thanks, but to do this I will have to change a lot in my existing app.. I am looking for example a simple CSS hack on the `scrollable` class (table container) or something like that :-) If no solutions are found then I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You yourself provide half of the solution, using `table-layout: fixed` works perfectly. But the content was looking horrible! So I resolved that issue. Just add this css -

```
.slide-content > table.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: it isn't working with you?? I edited the code now - https://jsbin.com/moguxejare/edit?html,output and now I'm seeing the 'click to enlarge' image is not floating right, have you made any changes to it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for example a simple CSS hack on the scrollable class (table container) or something like that

Have you tried `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` on the grey box `.col-sm-3`? That should take `.col-sm-3` out of the flow of the rest of the content (by default everything is `position: static`).

In doing so, `col-sm-3` will appear where you expect it to be no matter what the other "static" elements are doing, as long as you have no conflicting styles that is.

**UPDATE**: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/azkn7436/

### HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: lightgray; height:400px;">Aside Menu</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 slide-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="height: 250px; background-color: lightgreen">Some Label</div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9 scrollable">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem libero sequi tempore necessitatibus tempora, porro, iure, nisi dicta, rerum enim natus facilis voluptatum soluta dolore molestias vero odit eaque veniam.</p>
                                            <table class="table" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Hello</td>
                                                        <td>Lipsumdolor</td>
                                                        <td>Lipsum Gen</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Hello</td>
                                                        <td>Lipsumdolor</td>
                                                        <td>LipsumLipsumLipsumLipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                                                        <td>FSH 10%</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Hello</td>
                                                        <td>Lipsumdolor</td>
                                                        <td>Lipsum Gen</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                                                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                                                        <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                                                        <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                                                        <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                                                        <td>qwertyuiop</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="position: fixed; right:0; bottom: 50%">
                                    <img src="https://placehold.it/120x120">
                                    <br> <a href="#">Click to enlarge</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.scrollable {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width: 75%;
}
.scrollable table {
    margin: 0px;
    border-color: lightgray;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.slide-content {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
/*  st    .slide-content > table.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
} */
```

Your `.col-sm-3` is `position: fixed; bottom: 50%; right: 0;` Now you can stretch your table as wide as you want, there ain't no way the little grey box on the right will move.

Comment: The table still pushes the container's width. I added `position: absolute` on the `col-sm-3` element, and `position: relative` on its parent.

Comment: Just try adding `fixed` on the grey box, don't apply `position` to anything else including the parent. Also **do not** `float` it. Also set it to `right: 0;` If it's still wrong, then set `right: 10px` or `right: 1em` until it is correct. If you cannot move the grey box at all, then you should use Chrome Dev Tools and see it's computed style. If you don't know what I'm talking about, see this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles